# How to solve the differentiation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

It is given that, $x= \sin t$ and $y= \sin pt$
 we need to prove that, $$(1-x^2)y_2 -xy_1+p^2 y =0 $$
Where $y_1 $ = represents differentiation with respect to t. Is it possible or the question is wrong?

Comment: What is $y_2$? The second derivate with respect to $t$ ?

Comment: yes right you are.

Comment: Sorry it would be $p^2 y$

Comment: The first derivate is $p\ cos(pt)$, the second is $-p^2\  sin(pt)$. I cannot see how the terms can cancel out.

Comment: Or do I have to derivate $(1-x^2)y$ twice and $xy$ once ?

Comment: I think  the question is wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can get to your result is to try and go from 
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}\rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}$$
thus
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d}{dx} = \dot{x}\frac{d}{dx} 
$$
$$
\dot{x} = \cos t = \sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
therefore
$$
\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} = \sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{d}{dx}\right) = \left(1-x^2\right)\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} - \sqrt{1-x^2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\dfrac{d}{dx} 
$$
or
$$
\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} = \left(1-x^2\right)\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} -x\dfrac{d}{dx}
$$
thus working backwards so to speak
$$
\left(1-x^2\right)\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} -x\dfrac{d}{dx} + p^2 y =0 
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2} + p^2y = 0. \tag{*}
$$
if we take your equation and use the change of variable $x = \sin t$
so we know hwat the solutions to Eq. (*) are
$$
y = c_1\sin(pt) + c_2\cos (pt)
$$
where initial conditions will determine $c_1,c_2$. 
Hope it helps